# Node.js: Authorizing routes vs. authorizing methods

Tags: node.js, express, session, mongoose, authorization

#### Quick background

I am building an API with `Node.js`, `Express` and `Mongoose`. The authentication I implemented works with the `passport-headerapikey` package. I search the DB for the user with the api-key and add that user to the `req` Object. Thus ensuring my knowledge about the identity the whole time until the request ends.

#### Authorization

Let's get to the issue.

Up until now I called an `authorize() function` in every endpoint manually before doing anything. Like so:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  autorize('admin', req.user.role) // method is called at every route manually
    .then(() => {
      ... do stuff here 
    })
    .catch(err => req.status(403).send())
}
```

My colleague said to me it is not a good solution and, rather than just securing the endpoint itself, I should have a session management that makes the current user available globally so that I can authorize at any point in **every function** individually.

**Meaning:**
A Method `createUser(obj)` could then call inside itself an authorization method or check for a condition like so:

```
createUser(obj) {
  if (currentUser.role !== 'admin') {
    return false        
  }

  obj = new User(obj)
  return obj.save()
}
```

That would mean I would `return false` in every function if a condition is met. Accessing the globally available currentUser for that session. (e.g. `globalCurrentUser.role !== admin` or something along those lines)

#### My question(s)

1. Is it bad practice to just secure endpoints and not functions?
2. Can't I just require an extra param "auth" with every function, so that when called it needs to receive the `currentUser.role` like in my `authorize()` function or it returns false? That means I pass the user manually to every function or it will simply fail
3. If I should have a session management for global access of the user during the request: Do you have suggestions for frameworks?

Thanks in advance,
Benno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication and authorisation are two different things and should be treated separately. Authentication says "who are you?" and authorisation says "do you have permission?". Baring in mind that Express is designed entirely around middleware, I would do the following.

1. Abstract your authentication into a single piece of middleware which runs for all your endpoints using `app.use()` before you mount your router / routes.
2. Create an authorisation function which can be called from anywhere, it takes a user (or id or whatever you have) and a role, and it then checks if the user has that role.

Think of it like this, your authorisation will never change, it is core to your application. If you decided to ditch Expressjs and use Koa or move from traditional HTTP requests to Web Sockets you wouldn't want to change your authorisation logic. But your authentication may well change, you may wish to no longer use a header to store the token, perhaps you switch to cookies or something else entirely, you may wish to change this.

You'll end up with a piece of global middlware which checks an auth token and attaches the `user` object to the `req`. Then you'll have a utility function called something like `userHasRole` which will be called at any endpoint which requires a specific role within the application. You're then free to check permissions at any point in the application. This may be in very different places across your application, for instance you might check if they're an admin at the beginning of a request to some admin dashboard, but you might check permissions later on if they try to access a particular resource. When accessing a particular resource you might want to let them through and determine at the last minute if they have access to the resource. (It's hard to give a specific example without knowing more about your application).

In some instances it might be suitable to check at the beginning of the business logic, in other places it might make sense to check later on. This shouldn't matter, you should be able to run this check whenever you need to. This will depend entirely on the business logic and placing it in every single function ever may be useless if it's just formatting a string output, but it might be useful when trying to pull out a DB record.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I had in mind. So in that case i don’t need any *global* session management that makes a sessions user accessible from everywhere. Just a regular session or JWT solution that adds `user` to the `req` Object

Comment: You've already got session management with the header token and some code which fetches the user from the DB. That is the token someone uses to access your API with an identified account assuming I've got the right end of the stick (and that is done properly). Just create some middleware which takes that API key, finds the user it relates to and attach the `user` object to the `req` as you've said. This will be attached as middleware to run on every route. But you already seem to have session management so I don't understand why you need more of it?

Comment: My colleague just told me I'd need globally available session-information so that I can use some kind of "currentUser" information outside the route in my methods (e.g. `createUser()`). But as you already pointed out that is not the way to go, since that would create weird dependencies for functions that should be usable anywhere. Therefore we are going for middleware authorization.

The authentication is already solved, that case was closed all along.

So the question is actually closed, you are right, we are doing what I originally intended. Thanks so much!

Comment: I would suggest you speak to your colleague again and ask for more clarification. To me it looks like you are already doing that by attaching a req.user to your endpoint. I do not understand what they mean by a globally available session, it is available anywhere by virtue of your middleware. As mentioned, I still think this is the correct approach so the answer is correct, but it may be worth discussing it with your colleague again, just to make sure all is well :) Happy coding!